# binomial approximation doubt

Tags: binomial-theorem

suppose question is $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}$$ where $x<<1$
so answer will be $1-3x$ by binomial approximation.
But if we do binomial approximation in denominator itself,answer will be $\frac{1}{(1+3x)}$

so basically is it like we rationalise the second answer and then $1>>9x^2$ so we get 1-3x or is there some other reason?

Comment: Yes.  We have  $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}=1-3x+O(x^2)$$and $$\frac1{1+3x+O(x^2)}=1-3x+O(x^2)$$